# replacing trailing space in Pandas column

Tags: pandas, string, lambda, replace, apply

If I have a string with space at the end, I can use rstrip() to remove the trailing space.

```
word='- Keane '
"".join(word.rstrip())
```

it returns '- Keane' which is what I want.

However, it dsnt do the same when passing it through a pandas column using apply method. here is what I have (two first row of the column WL2019['Location']):

Location

```
'-Keane '
'- PBC-CALTEX '
```

I want:

```
'- Keane'
'- PBC-CALTEX'
```

The code I use:

```
WL2019['NewLoc']=WL2019['Location'].apply(lambda x: "".join(str(x).rstrip()))
```

But it dsnt do anything. It basically outputs the same as column Location. Does anyone know why and how can get this fixed?
Thanks

EDIT: okay, I failed to explain clearly what I have been doing. This is the problem:

I had a string column that had to extract part of entries between two dahesh. like this:

```
'v102- Keane - ARC'
'v103- PBC-CALTEX -BARS'
```

I used the code below to extarct the middle part. Once you do that, the output is in List type in each entry. We cant use strip() for lists. I had to go through  mumbo jumbo below to fix it. I found the solution but not efficient yet. I might post the better solution later.

```
def location(a):
    
    pat=r'[\s]+[\w\W]+[\s]+'
    pattern=re.compile(pat, re.IGNORECASE)
    
    return re.findall(pattern,a)
    
    
WL2019['NewLoc']=WL2019['Account'].apply(location)    

WL2019['NewLoc']=WL2019['NewLoc'].apply(lambda x: str(x).strip('[]'))
WL2019['NewLoc']=WL2019['NewLoc'].apply(lambda x: str(x).strip("''"))
WL2019['NewLoc']=WL2019['NewLoc'].apply(lambda x: str(x).strip('""'))
WL2019['NewLoc'] = WL2019['NewLoc'].replace('- ','', regex=True).replace(' -', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: You code is working. you can try this also no need of .join df['Manufacturer']=df['Manufacturer'].apply(lambda x: x.rstrip())

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas.Series.str.rstrip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html)-

```
WL2019['NewLoc']=WL2019['Location'].str.rstrip()
```